# Spherical Capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

How would we derive the equation for the capacitance of a spherical capacitor when the inner sphere has been earthed?
I am aware of the formula $\frac{4\pi \epsilon_0}{\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}}$ (R1, R2 are the radii of the two spheres), does that also apply when the outer sphere has been earthed?

Comment: It seems that your question is not well-liked here.  You might get a better response at physicsforums.com

Answer (score 2):

In a spherical capacitor, you have two conductive concentric spherical shells. Since a spherically distributed charge can be modeled as a point charge (and you can prove this by using Gauss's law with a spherical gaussian surface assuming spherical symmetry) the potential between the two shells is:
$$\Delta V = k_eQ[\frac{1}{R_2} - \frac{1}{R_1} ]$$

Since capacitance is $C = \frac{Q}{\Delta V}$:
$$C = \frac{Q}{k_eQ[\frac{1}{R_2} - \frac{1}{R_1} ]}=\frac{R_1R_2}{k_e(R_2-R_1)}$$

Now you can notice that $Q$ is the charge on each shell. Earthing one shell (either of the two) has the same effect as charging that shell with the equal and opposite charge of the other. Nevertheless, the capacitance of a spherical capacitor, like most configurations, is not dependent on charge.

Edit: If it helps, you can ignore the outer shell when regarding the potential difference between the surfaces. This is because the electric field due to the charge distribution over the outer shell is zero inside it.